# 100% clustered and stack chart plotting in python or excel

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I want to plot a chart using python or excel (currently done in excel but it doesn't do the thing I want to achieve).  I will explain what I did currently,
I want to plot the following nutrient data of ingredients `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` and `E` in a stacked and cluster bar chart.below is the data.

[image]

After the column `E`, it shows the maximum threshold value for each nutrient.
What I need is following. I will use an example.  consider the raw `fat`, we have 5 ingredients and total of fat from the 5 ingredients is `92.52+0.06+0.44+0+39.05=132.07`. This was plotted in a stack graph in the image below. However, this has exceeded the maximum value of 65. if 65 is considered as 100% , the total fat column should show 203.18% which is way higher than the max value. Like this for each nutrient there should be two stacked columns, one shows the reference value and other shows the currently calculated value.

What I got is in excel is below. It takes both values to 100% so cant compare it.
[image]

I use paint to draw what I really wanted to show.(For fat bar only)
[image]

Can anyone help me with this using excel or Python (I am also familiar with Python and I think excel cant do this). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry It must have suggested and I have mistakenly click it. I dont know `R` could be of help for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first suggest transforming your data into percentage and putting it into a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe). To follow your example, this means take the row labeled 'fat' as an array, divide it by the maximum (in this case 65) and multiply by 100.

```
fat = np.array([92.52, 0.06, 0.44, 0.0, 39.5])
fat_pct = (fat / 65) * 100
```

Once you have your transformed data, assemble it into a DataFrame using something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([fat_pct, cal_pct, ...],
                  index=['fat (%)', 'calories (%)', ...],
                  columns=['A', 'B', ...])
```

Now you can use the `plot()` method to generate a stacked bar chart like so:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Another way to create the stacked bar chart after transforming your data is to make use of the `bottom` keyword argument to the `plt.bar()` function. This allows you to set the value at which the bottom of the bar is placed. To get a plot that looks like your diagram, you could plot group A, then plot group B with group A's values as the bottom, plot group C with group B's values as the bottom, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me a good logic to achieve this. But I want that 65 as the 100% mark which seems to be somewhat difficult to add to this `pandas df` because of different number of columns in it.

Comment: You can pass a matplotlib `axes` object to `df.plot()` using the `ax` keyword argument and then plot the additional bars on top.